# Application of null pointer

Tags: c, pointers, null-pointer

I was giving interview in a company and they asked me "What are applications of null pointers in C"? I told them what null pointer is and how it leads to segmentation fault. However, they were not happy with the answer. I have never heard anything like this before. If anyone has any idea, please share.

Thank you

Comment: How does it lead to a segfault? I thought that only occurs when you attempt to deference it, because it doesn't really point to anything in memory, thus the segfault. But yes + 1 for this question. The only application I can think of is to have it as a marker to indicate that a pointer has not been allocated memory or as a signal of failure during that situation.

Comment: in C++ we used them to mark the end or beginning of chained data structures - hmm. I hate interview(er) questions

Answer (score 3):

they were asking when you need to use NULL pointers, not when they lead to problems.

The classic answer is that they are used when there is nothing to point to. For example the next pointer in a list when its the end of a list -> there is no next item.

and so in your code you go

```
if(nextItem != NULL)
{
  // do stuff with nextItem
}
else
{
// the end
}
```

As mooseboy points out this is a sentinel value i.e, a special value that your code recognizes as having a deciding value.

NULL is the perfect pointer sentinel since NULL is assumed to never be a valid value for a pointer (for example you could not use 0x000042 since 42 might be a real address)

Comment: When used in this way, you're using NULL (0) as a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).  It doesn't *really* mean address `0x00000000`, it has a special meaning.

Comment: @MooseBoys: who talked about address 0? In C NULL is *by definition* a sentinel value (it's a pointer value that is not a trap representation, that is guaranteed not to be taken by any valid object and that leads to undefined behavior when dereferenced), which in line of principle has nothing do with what is at address 0 of the address space.

Comment: @Matteo - that wasnt me - but FYI. I grew up on a machine where NULL was 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: @pm100: actually, that would not be C-standard compliant; it's required by the standard that NULL "appears" to be 0 to your C code (IIRC there have been some compilers that went to great length to make sure that this illusion held true even on platforms where 0 was a valid address - you *write* or *compare* to zero, but the underlying bit pattern could be anything).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: He's not saying that a C nullpointer wasn't correctly translated to a machine nullpointer. He's saying that the machine-nullpointer wasn't all-bits-zero.

Comment: @Deduplicator: in that case we are saying the same thing :)

Answer (score -3):

This question is kind of vague, but one thing they might have been unhappy about is that from a pure language perspective, dereferencing `NULL` is not guranteed to cause a segfault. It causes unspecified behavior, i.e. the language doesn't say what will happen. On most platforms, yes, null reference causes a segfault, but an implementation of C could do something else and still conform to the standard.

Comment: Are you *sure* most platforms are PCs, or at least have an MMU? There are far more embedded systems...

Comment: The question is flagged in C, and in Linux, an attempt to deference a null pointer results a consistent behaviour == segfault :)
You are correct though. Windows and other OSs may behave differently

Comment: @rurouni88: Not really, even if you make the absolutely unwarranted assumption of using Linux. One *can* map the 0-address, with enough priviliges, and anyway on kernel-side things are even more interesting.

Comment: @Deduplicator in C *how* would you map the 0 address and distinguish the pointer from NULL?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Look at the comment I responded to. Then your question will stop making sense.

Comment: @Deduplicator so you would prefer to put down my question than answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane, there's no reason the null pointer representation has to be all-zero-bits. In such an implementation you could map the 0 address and distinguish from the null pointer.

Comment: @CarlNorum thanks, but does that mean one should explicitly test for a valid pointer with, for example `if (ptr!=NULL)` rather than with `if (ptr)`?

Comment: No, a null pointer is guaranteed to evaluate as false.